# & sign is not echoed out

Tags: php, html

I have the following:

```
$A= Today-&-Tomorrow;
```

I want to echo out $A as follows:
Today & Tomorrow

I have tried this:

```
echo str_replace('-', ' ',$A)
```

This results in Today 
 it will NOT echo out `& Tomorrow`
I know the problem is the & sign however I do not know how to solve this I tried `&amp;` 
Any help welcome

Comment: Is that your actual code?!?!  _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put single quotes for your **$A** as follows:

```
$A = 'Today-&-Tomorrow';
echo str_replace('-', ' ',$A); // outputs Today & Tomorrow
```